# How to deal with masked/fuzzy node in graph classification?

Tags: classification, missing-data, graph-neural-network

I’m new to graph embeddings, and I have some trouble formulating a solution

Suppose that I have a generic node classification dataset that tell the directed edge links between each node along with its weight. Each node has an identification sequence such as “123456”, or “ab2681”. The problem arise when the edge link is defined but the destination node is only partial e.g. “ab2681” can become “ab268x”, “ab26xx”, or “abxxxx”. I’m not sure how to handle this kind of masking

I have some guess like the node if we have node name of “ab2861”, and “ab2867”. If the mask weight occurred we can make a new graph that both update “ab2861”, and “ab2867” using half of its original weight (?). But I’m not sure this is a good idea. So any other ideas?

Thanks in advance